# Does the speed of the Refracted Ray change if the angle of Incidence is 0 degrees?

Tags: refraction

While studying about Refraction, the following doubt came into my mind. The author of the textbook mentions that if the light wave is incident normal to the surface, it will travel "undeviated" in the other medium. Shouldn't this fact imply that the wave velocity in the other medium is the same as the light is not really "bent" or refracted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.Law of refraction is $$n_1\sin \theta_1=n_2\sin \theta_2$$ If $\theta_1=0$ as $n_1\neq0$ and $n_2\neq 0$ we have $\theta_2=0$.There is conclusion on $n_1$ and $n_2$.And if $n_\neq n_2$ then $v_1 \neq v_2$ and $v=\frac{c}{n}$ .Velocity of light is same in any direction.It changes only if $n$ changes.